# How to get just one special character in a string before a letter and insert a comma between them?

Tags: regex, special-characters

I'm trying to insert a comma between a string, like `hello)))how are you`, I just want to insert it between the `)` + letter, I mean, `hello))),how are you`.

How can I do this using regular expressions and `preg_replace`?

I have tried using `"/(\)+[a-z]){1}/g"` but it takes all the `)`, not just the first one before the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
$result = preg_replace('~\)+\K(?=[a-z])~', ',', $s);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBmPcV/1). Case insensitive variation: `'~\)+\K(?=[a-z])~i'`.

**Details**

- `\)+` -  matches 1+ `)` chars
- `\K` - omits the matched `)` chars from the match
- `(?=[a-z])` - requires a lowercase letter immediately to the right of the current location without adding it to the match value.

Alternative:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(\)+)([a-z])~', '$1,$2', $s);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBmPcV/2). Case insensitive variation: `'~(\)+)([a-z])~i'`.

Here, `(\)+)([a-z])` captures the close parentheses into Group 1 and then the letter is captured into Group 2 and the replacement is the value in Group 1 + `,` + the value in Group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(\))([^)])
```

Replacement string:

```
\1,\2
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/lNR5Mw/1).

---

Above regex finds a `)` followed by anything which is not a `)`. If you want to restrict the find to letters only, you may change the regex to:

```
(\))([a-zA-Z])
```